# What's the right format to create a PHP DateTime instance of '2016.04.30 PM 7:30' via DateTime::createFromFormat?

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime, date-formatting

I'm currently working on a Wordpress project where I should get some custom post metadata, convert it to a `DateTime` instance, and do the math with it.

When I `echo` the get_post_meta, it looks as follows.

> 2016.04.30 PM 7:30

The format I'm using to get a `DateTime` instance is as follows.

> Y.m.d A g:i

But the return value of `DateTime::createFromFormat` is `false`.

```
// 2016.04.30 PM 7:30
$start_at = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'Y.m.d A g:i', get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'as_date', true));
if ($start_at === false) {
    echo 'False format: ' . get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'as_date', true);
} else {
    echo $start_at->getTimestamp();
}
```

The result is `False format: 2016.04.30 PM 7:30`.

What am I missing here? I think it must be something trivial but I can't get through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testing, I found that the problem character in the format was the 'A'. So I poked around and found this [bug in PHP](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64975) (that is apparently not a bug at all!)

Going through the [source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/date/lib/parse_date.c#L24954), it looks like it will not parse AM and PM until after an hour has been already parsed.

Probably your best bet would be a quick pass through a regular expression to move the AM/PM to the end:

```
$thedate = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'as_date', true);
$thedate = preg_replace("/([0-9.]+) ([ap]m) ([0-9:]+)/i", "$1 $3 $2", $thedate);
$start_at = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y.m.d g:i A', $thedate);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the date format and try `createFromFormat`

```
$non_standard_format  = '2016.04.30 PM 7:30';
$non_standard_format = str_replace('.','-',$non_standard_format);
$date_components = explode(" ",$non_standard_format);
$standard_format = $date_components[0]." ".$date_components[2]." ".$date_components[1];
```

Then try passing this to `DateTime::createFromFormat`

```
$start_at = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'Y-m-d g:i A', $standard_format);
if ($start_at === false) {
    echo 'False format: ' . get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'as_date', true);
} else {
    echo $start_at->getTimestamp();
}
```

[Supported date formats in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

Comment: Don't forget to change the format string from `'Y.m.d A g:i'` to `'Y-m-d g:i A'` in your example.